# JSF RichFaces:a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor behaviour for zebra table

Tags: jsf, richfaces, mouseover, zebra-striping

jsf:

```
<rich:dataTable id="files" styleClass="table" headerClass="header"
value="#{file}" var="fileRecord" rendered="#{file.rowCount>0}"
rowClasses="even,odd" onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'"
onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'">
<rich:column>
```

precondition:
have zebra styled table with white and gray colored rows
steps:
**1.** mouse hover on row,it's hovered ok
**2.** mouse out and it becomes white

postcondition:
table lost its "zebraness"

It's occurred bevcause of `#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}` evaluated to white color.
How to preserve zebra styling?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be changed to:

```
#{a4jSkin.rowBackgroundColor}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<rich:dataTable id="files" styleClass="table" headerClass="header"
  value="#{file}" var="fileRecord" rendered="#{file.rowCount lt 0}"
  rowClasses="even,odd" 
  onRowMouseOver="tableRowColor=this.style.backgroundColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor='#dedede'"
  onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor=tableRowColor">
<rich:column>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would work? I understand that `onRowMouseOut` the table's background color would be changed to the (undefined) "tableRowColor" variable?

Comment: When mouseOver is detected it saves the current backgroundColor in the variable named tableRowColor then it assigns the colour #dedede. When the mouse is out it assigns the style stored in tableRowColor variable. It is working for me right now.

Comment: I still don't think relying on globals like that is a good idea (read: a terrible hack) but I see what you're after.